# Документация при разработке iOS приложений

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, документация, мобильная-разработка

Собственно вопрос (с точки зрения разработчика и написания кода на Swift/Objective C). 
Существуют ли какие-либо общепринятые стандарты ведения такой документации?

В компаниях, в которых я работал, все ограничивалось кратким описанием проекта (и архитектуры проекта) в произвольном стиле (в виде текстового файла), задачами в таск-менеджере, и комментариями в коде (в начале файла, и в случае неинтуитивности функции - перед функцией).

В то же время, серверный RESTful код документировался с использованием Swagger и его аналогов (на выходе получался мини web-сайт с описаниями всех запросов и параметров).

Приветствуются любые ответы по теме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону автоматического документирования кода, например, jazzy:
https://github.com/realm/jazzy

Comment: Спасибо, похоже это действительно то, что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Для документирования используем Confluence.

Из Википедии: вики-система для внутреннего использования организациями с целью создания единой базы знаний.

Плюсы: удобный инструмент с точки зрения доступа, наполнения и поддержания актуальной информации о проекте.

Минусы: необходимость ручного поддержания актуальности информации.

Comment: Дополните свой ответ еще какой нибудь информацией. Например, какие у него плюсы, почему его используют.